# Can I split text from one column into to two existing columns in My SQL

Tags: mysql, query, update, split

```
SELECT `Appointment`,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Appointment`, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS Date,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Appointment`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS Time
   FROM go_applicants
```

which separates the date and time but creates 2 new columns, is it possible to insert/update this split into existing columns in the table.

This would allow me then to run this as an event instead and continually update the table.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Appointment` column ???

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE go_applicants \G` and display the output.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please **always** include your version of MySQL with your questions - the answer can depend critically on this! Also, the information @RolandoMySQLDBA requested is also essential for many/most questions! I **really, really** hope that you're not storing `DATETIME`s or `TIMESTAMP`s as strings - there are **all sorts** of reasons why this isn't a good idea!

Comment: _Usually_ having "date" and "time" in separate columns makes queries messier.  Think through whether this split will help or hurt.  Sketch out the new `SELECTs` and `UPDATEs`.

Comment: See the datetime functions for splitting a `DATETIME`.  Do _not_ store a datetime in a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: HI All, interesting comments my mysql version is 5.6 and its a wordpress website that captures the data with a couple of plugins (which causes the issue).  If the plugin had the option to have separate date and time that would have been so much easier but my PHP lacks skill set (at the moment).  The users on the front end needed functionality to be able to sort data, the problem arises because the users can't no matter how the table is set. so the simplest option was to run an event periodically which automatically separated the two column allowing for a better user experience.

Comment: Please add any supplementary information from comments into the question itself - use the `edit` link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store in existing columns:

```sql
UPDATE go_applicants
SET cDate = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Appointment`, ' ', 1),
    cTime = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Appointment`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1);
```

Make generated columns:

```sql
ALTER TABLE go_applicants
    ADD COLUMN cDate DATE AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Appointment`, ' ', 1)),
    ADD COLUMN cTime TIME AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Appointment`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1));
```

PS. If you store date and time of some datetime value in 2 separate static columns - this is "bad practice" in most cases.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, the main part of the is driven by wordpress plugins which control appointment scheduling which brings the information in as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm but the user view can not not sort the data easily which is why I wanted to split the text.  now the users front end see it as a set date and a set time with sorting functionality.  it didn't matter what I set up for the database or input methods and until I brush up on php this was pretty much my last resort